# JMeter: How can I convert string to Date time in JMeter?

Tags: string, datetime, jmeter, type-conversion

We are injecting current date/time ${__time(yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm.sss'Z',)} to get date/time something like this 2021-12-12T12:29:59.999Z but it shows error as "Could not convert string to DateTime".

How may I achieve this?

Comment: Where are you using the date? any JSR / Beanshell processors or Post body

Comment: Using on post body

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting `Could not convert string to DateTime` from the application you're testing - then you're sending the date in wrong format and we cannot help here because we don't know what kind of date does your server expect.

If you're trying to generate the date in [ISO8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) - here is the correct format:

```
yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'
```

---

On the other hand if you cannot generate the date in JMeter - I cannot reproduce it using the latest JMeter 5.4.1 and the function syntax you provided:

[image]

Just in case here is mine:

```
${__time(yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm.sss'Z',)}
```

If it doesn't work for

- you first of all check [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) for any suspicious entries
- then make sure that you have `ApacheJMeter_functions.jar` file under "lib/ext" function of your JMeter installation. If you don't - re-install it using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager/)
- as the last resort you can get brand new JMeter version from its [downloads](https://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi) page